# Error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or Unexpected Token", When Deploying Site on Netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, netlify

I can run the following commands just fine, without error: `npm start`, `npm run build` and `pm2 start server.js`. However, when I attempt to deploy my project on Netlify I get the following error in the Chrome console: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**, the returned page is blank and I do not get an error in the Netlify build log. I do not know why this is happening or how to fix it. Please help me out as soon as possible.

**server.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = 4000;

const root = require("path").join(__dirname, "build");
app.use(express.static(root));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root });
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}`));
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jw-react-pagination": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-player": "^1.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**error Message:**

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

**netlify : build log:**

```
10:53:05 AM: Build ready to start
10:53:08 AM: build-image version: b0258b965567defc4a2d7e2f2dec2e00c8f73ad6
10:53:08 AM: build-image tag: v3.4.1
10:53:08 AM: buildbot version: 648208d76731cd5bca75c1e9bc99d2032a1f1473
10:53:08 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:53:08 AM: Starting to download cache of 140.6MB
10:53:08 AM: Finished downloading cache in 807.309358ms
10:53:08 AM: Starting to extract cache
10:53:15 AM: Finished extracting cache in 6.082087117s
10:53:15 AM: Finished fetching cache in 7.016759665s
10:53:15 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:53:15 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
10:53:18 AM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'build' versus 'build/' in the Netlify UI
10:53:18 AM: Starting build script
10:53:18 AM: Installing dependencies
10:53:18 AM: Python version set to 2.7
10:53:19 AM: Started restoring cached node version
10:53:22 AM: Finished restoring cached node version
10:53:23 AM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
10:53:24 AM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
10:53:24 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
10:53:24 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
10:53:24 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
10:53:26 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
10:53:26 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
10:53:26 AM: 5.2 is already installed.
10:53:26 AM: Using Swift version 5.2
10:53:26 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
10:53:26 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
10:53:27 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
10:53:27 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
10:53:27 AM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
10:53:27 AM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
10:53:27 AM: Installing missing commands
10:53:27 AM: Verify run directory
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
10:53:28 AM: │        Netlify Build        │
10:53:28 AM: └─────────────────────────────┘
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: ❯ Version
10:53:28 AM:   @netlify/build 4.0.4
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: ❯ Flags
10:53:28 AM:   deployId: 5f6c2d1e14a2c400079aabfa
10:53:28 AM:   mode: buildbot
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: ❯ Current directory
10:53:28 AM:   /opt/build/repo
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: ❯ Config file
10:53:28 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: ❯ Context
10:53:28 AM:   production
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
10:53:28 AM: │ 1. Build command from Netlify app │
10:53:28 AM: └───────────────────────────────────┘
10:53:28 AM: ​
10:53:28 AM: $ npm run build
10:53:28 AM: > project@0.1.0 build /opt/build/repo
10:53:28 AM: > react-scripts build
10:53:30 AM: Creating an optimized production build...
10:53:38 AM: Compiled successfully.
10:53:38 AM: 
10:53:38 AM: File sizes after gzip:
10:53:39 AM:   3.99 MB   build/static/js/main.32349faf.chunk.js
10:53:39 AM:   49.51 KB  build/static/js/2.0e21026f.chunk.js
10:53:39 AM:   2.65 KB   build/static/css/main.6ddef2a7.chunk.css
10:53:39 AM:   769 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.f16ea130.js
10:53:39 AM: The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
10:53:39 AM: You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
10:53:39 AM: The build folder is ready to be deployed.
10:53:39 AM: You may serve it with a static server:
10:53:39 AM:   npm install -g serve
10:53:39 AM:   serve -s build
10:53:39 AM: Find out more about deployment here:
10:53:39 AM:   bit.ly/CRA-deploy
10:53:39 AM: ​
10:53:39 AM: (build.command completed in 11.3s)
10:53:39 AM: ​
10:53:39 AM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
10:53:39 AM: │   Netlify Build Complete    │
10:53:39 AM: └─────────────────────────────┘
10:53:39 AM: ​
10:53:39 AM: (Netlify Build completed in 11.3s)
10:53:40 AM: Caching artifacts
10:53:40 AM: Started saving node modules
10:53:40 AM: Finished saving node modules
10:53:40 AM: Started saving build plugins
10:53:40 AM: Finished saving build plugins
10:53:40 AM: Started saving pip cache
10:53:40 AM: Finished saving pip cache
10:53:40 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Started saving go dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
10:53:40 AM: Build script success
10:53:40 AM: Starting to deploy site from 'build'
10:53:40 AM: Creating deploy tree 
10:53:40 AM: Creating deploy upload records
10:53:40 AM: 0 new files to upload
10:53:40 AM: 0 new functions to upload
10:53:40 AM: Starting post processing
10:53:40 AM: Post processing - HTML
10:53:40 AM: Post processing - header rules
10:53:40 AM: Post processing - redirect rules
10:53:40 AM: Post processing done
10:53:40 AM: Site is live
10:54:04 AM: Finished processing build request in 56.875804209s
```

**cmd: npm run build**

```
C:\Users\prash\Desktop\site>npm run build

> project@0.1.0 build C:\Users\prash\Desktop\site
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  3.99 MB   build\static\js\main.bd1fe936.chunk.js
  49.51 KB  build\static\js\2.0e21026f.chunk.js
  2.65 KB   build\static\css\main.6ddef2a7.chunk.css
  769 B     build\static\js\runtime-main.f16ea130.js


The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy

C:\Users\prash\Desktop\site>pm2 start server.js
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [server](ids: [ 0 ])
[PM2] [server](0) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started

┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ server    │ default     │ 0.1.0   │ fork    │ 8572     │ 0s     │ 2    │ online    │ 0%       │ 33.1mb   │ prash    │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: What does your server console say?

Comment: when i run pm2 start server.js or npm run build  every thing is  fine but when deployed on netlify i got error.

Comment: Please post the package.json and the error message as text, not screenshots.

Comment: okay now you can see .thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your support 

Actually error in **Json file**  some places double quote ("  ")  converted into other format of double quote (“ ”) and also some places  added some extra symbols as well.
so i formatted and validate my JSON file with the help of online tools and its fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your console.log need ``

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: actually when i copied my code here than i missed it in my code `` is included

Comment: maybe is the Template Literal, try to change the message with  normal quotes

Comment: if it is not recognize Template Literal  it means it is not recognize New feature or function  of ES6 like: Arrow function also.